# Granular Windows firewall rule control

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, firewall, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

Is there a way using group policy (or some other built in mechanism) to apply firewall rules in such a way that a subset of the rules are locked and cannot be changed or overridden, but another subset can? For example I want to lock down the Core networking rules and/or File Sharing rules so that local admins cannot change them, BUT, they can add rules to open up ports for SQL, IIS, etc...

I know with group policy you can have it not merge rules, but that is more of a hammer like approach. I would need something more granular.

Can this be done with built in tools? Or would we need a 3rd party managed firewall application of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible with built in tools. BUT, it can be done with third party firewall management.